# Firebase Analytics Screentime by user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase provides Screentime but that is of all users which includes guest too.
Is there any way to monitor it by User?

Comment: have you tried using setUserID:? It will set user property for each event so you can filter out by users (those that have user IDs vs non)

Comment: @adbitx setUserID how to do it on screenTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setUserID:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics#/c:objc(cs)FIRAnalytics(cm)setUserID:) once a user logs into their account. All of the subsequent events will have the user property with the user ID, including screen view events. You can then query for the all the screen events that have non-null user ID and those that have no user ID (guests) to calculate the screen time using BigQuery, or you can try to filter user property on the dashboard but I'm not sure how to do it in your case.